# Should I require my own packages as a dependency or should I just include them

Tags: node.js, npm, package

I'm wondering what the best or commonly used approach is when you publish a javascript package to npm/github. I've just published one that parses and saves xml and csv data to a database.

For this package, I've created some other packages like

1. a logger
2. a model creator
3. some Map() prototypes
4. a little "ORM" for mysql

While the model creator is mainly for the main package itself (only creates models for the xml/csv parsing), the rest could be used in different projects as well.

What's the commonly used approach here? Should I create a different package for all of the different tools and then require them in my package.json file, or should I just include the files in the main project and create a single package for all?

Are there any differences at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A package should be any coherent, logically grouped set of functionalities, that makes sense if used in more then a single, specific project.

If you feel any of your "other packages" fit this description, publish them!

Comment: sounds reasonable. Let's publish then... :)